# Is the following operator positive?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, positive-matrices

Let $M$ be some bounded positive operator with bound $\lVert M\rVert<1$ and let $\rho$ be a positive trace class, self adjoint operator with norm $\lVert\rho\rVert=1$. Assume that these operators act on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space (I don't think that the dimension matters to be honest). Is the following true?

$$ 
\rho\geq M\rho M
$$
in other words is the the operator $\rho- M\rho M$ positive? Yet again in other words, is the following true?

$$
 \langle v, \rho v\rangle \geq \langle v, M\rho M v\rangle 
$$
for any $v$ in the Hibert space that $\rho$ and $M\rho M$ are acting on.

Comment: There might be a problem as the operator $M\rho N$ is not necessarily self-adjoint. Hence the right hand side of the last inequality may be a nonreal number.

Comment: You are correct Ryszard, in the end I am interested in the case where $M$ is self adjoint and $N = M^{\dagger}$.  I see that you have implemented this hypothesis in your result.

Comment: Ryszard Szwarc I have fixed my question.

Comment: The assumption $M$ positive implies $M$ is self-adjoint. So $M^{\dagger}$ is equal $M.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I have fixed this. Now, for the case where M is not positive nor self adjoint I immagine that a similar hypothesis, namely $\rho\geq M\rho M^{\dagger}$ is also false. Do you have any intuition on this that you can spare. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is false as it does not hold for $M$ self-adjoint and even positive, for which $M=M^{\dagger}.$ The problem is that $M$ is located outside. For example  $\rho -\sqrt{\rho}MM^{\dagger}\sqrt{\rho}$ is positive. Now $M$ is inside.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc I see I see, thank you. It looks like the only case where $\rho \geq M\rho M^{\dagger}$ is the special case where $M$ is a projector. But projectors have $\|M\| = 1$ and this violates my assumption $\|M\|<1$. Thanks again fo the ongoing discussion.

Comment: You welcome  You may consider $M=rP$ where $P$ is a projection and $0<r<1.$ But it still fails. In my example when $a=b$ the operator $M$ is equal $2a$ times a projection. I have assumed $b>a$ to get $M$ strictly positive.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Very interesting, so it seems that commutativity between $\rho$ and $M$ is the key ingredient if $\rho - M\rho M^{\dagger}\geq 0$ is to hold. i.e. we require that $[\rho, M] = 0$ since then $\rho - M\rho M^{\dagger} = \rho -\sqrt{\rho}MM^{\dagger} \sqrt{\rho}$ which is positive as you stated. I am using the fact that $[\rho, M]= 0$ implies  $[\sqrt{\rho}, M] = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality does not hold even for two dimensional space.
For $0<\delta<1$ and $ 0<a<b<{1\over 2}$
let $${\rho} =\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&\delta\end{pmatrix},\quad M =\begin{pmatrix} b&a\\ a&b\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $\|\rho\|=1,$ $M>0$ and $\|M\|=a+b<1$ and $$ M{\rho} M= \begin{pmatrix} b^2+\delta a^2&(1+\delta) ab\\ (1+\delta)ab & \delta b^2+a^2\end{pmatrix}$$ Hence
$$\rho -M\rho M= \begin{pmatrix} 1-b^2-\delta a^2&-(1+\delta)ab\\ -(1+\delta)ab&\delta-\delta b^2-a^2\end{pmatrix}$$
For $\delta={1\over 25},$  $ a={1\over 5}$ and $b={1\over 4}$ we get
$$\delta-\delta b^2-a^2=-\delta b^2=-\textstyle {1\over 400 }<0$$
Hence the matrix $\rho -M\rho M$ is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: For finite dimensional matricese, I was under the impression that one needed to show that $Tr(A)\geq 0$ and $det(A)\geq 0$ was satisfied in order to prove that $A$ was positive. How does the result $\delta -\delta b^{2}-a^{2} <0$ reconcile with the result I have stated?

Comment: All entries on the main diagonal should be nonnegative, because $\langle Ce_i,e_i\rangle =c_{ii}$ for a matrix $C.$ Your criterion works only in dimension $2.$ In my example the determinant is negative, but it is simpler to inspect $c_{22}.$

Comment: Ah I see!!! Thank you very much for your thoughtful comment!